# Dictionary object receiving AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, attributeerror

I'm trying to pull a key-value pair from a dictionary that is contained within this list. The list is a set of lines containing line-level information about a payment in a third-party application.

```
[{'Amount': 45.0,'LinkedTxn': [{'TxnId': '129', 'TxnType': 'Invoice'}]}]
```

The list is a set of lines containing line-level information about a payment in a third-party application. Here's the code I'm using here.

```
lines = payment.get("Line")
for line in lines:
    link = line.get("LinkedTxn")[0]
    if link.get("TxnType") == "Invoice":
        line_no += 1
        invoice = line.get("LinkedTxn").get("TxnType")
        amount = line.get("Amount")
```

My expectation was that I would be able to get the value of `line('Amount')`, `LinkedTxn.TxnType`, and `LinkedTxn.TxnId`, which I would then save off into an array for later.

Instead, I can get the dictionary itself fine but, when I try to pull the value of `LinkedTxn`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Archangel16179/Development/business/main.py", line 142, in <module>
    payments = qb.get_payments("2021-01-01")
  File "/Users/Archangel16179/Development/business/app/services/service.py", line 143, in get_payments
    link = line.get("LinkedTxn")[0]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

When I put a breakpoint before the last line, I'm able call `amount = line.get('Amount')` without issue and then write out `amount` to receive the correct value. Additionally, I did a check with `whatis line` and it was returned as a dictionary as expected.

```
(Pdb) link = line.get("LinkedTxn")[0]
(Pdb) pp link
{'TxnId': '129', 'TxnType': 'Invoice'}
(Pdb) whatis line
<class 'dict'>
(Pdb) whatis link
<class 'dict'>
```

I've also tried just getting the list in `LinkedTxn` on one line and then taking the first value on the next line. That didn't change the result.

Comment: you've got, a "list" just as the error message says, not a dictionary. Remeber that JSON objects can have both dictionary and lists as containers, when "thawned" into Python objects.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `line.get("LinkedTxn")[0]`, what do you think is the value of `line`? In particular, do you think it is a `dict`, or a `list`? *Did you try to check* your expectation? (Hint: where the error message says `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'`, what do you suppose might be the `'list' object` that it's talking about?)

Comment: At any rate, please read [ask] and [mre]. We do not provide a [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) service, and we cannot test this code, because we do not have a way to re-create the initial `payment` value.

Comment: This sounds like you've got inconsistently-structured data - your outer list contains mostly dicts, but at least one list has somehow got in there.

Comment: "Additionally, I did a check with whatis line and it was returned as a dictionary as expected." - yes, you did this **once**. However, the code says `for line in lines:`, therefore `line` will have a *different value each time through the loop*. Presumably, one or more of them *isn't* as you expect. There is nothing about either JSON or Python that requires everything in the same input sequence to be the same type. When debugging, it's important to capture the values of variables **when the problem occurs**.

Comment: For example, one useful strategy may be to add exception handling, and break into the debugger in the `except` block.

Comment: Hey, Karl  - you know you can simply run your code with `python -m pdb programname.py` instead of adding a try/except/breakpoint block, don't you?

Comment: After Karl's comment suggesting using a try-break structure, the issue completely went away. None of the lines hit the exception and wrote out a breakpoint. This also occurred after I removed the try-except to see if I'd changed anything.

I was going to edit my question with a minimum, reproducible example, but it no longer appears to be necessary.

Comment: To clarify - I meant that after I followed the suggestion in that comment and added a try-break.

Answer (score 0):

```
payment = {"Line": [{'Amount': 45.0, 'LinkedTxn': [{'TxnId': '129', 'TxnType': 'Invoice'}]}]}
lines = payment.get("Line")
line_no = 0
for line in lines:
    if line['LinkedTxn'][0]['TxnType'] == "Invoice":
        line_no += 1
        invoice = line['LinkedTxn'][0]['TxnType']
        amount = line['Amount']
print(line_no)
```

You should try this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).